# Set an initial hour to the timer component

Tags: c#, time, timer, hour

I'm doing an C# application and I need to use the component Timer based to the hour. What I wanna know is if it's possible to set a beginning time for it. For example, I want it to starts ate 8:00AM and keep working all day long.

Comment: The timer works on increments not time.  There are several question here on how to synch it to the quarter hour etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just calculate the Interval to the next hour.  For example:

```
    private void SetTimer() {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var next = now.Date.AddHours(now.Hour + 1);
        var msec = (next - now).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Interval = (int)msec;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SetTimer();
        // etc...
    }
```

Call SetTimer() to get it started.

Answer (score 0):

The timer only fires an event based on the interval. If you set the interval to an hour, then you will get an event every hour.

A clock component would have a timer. The clock component would have all the logic for the initial time of the clock. It would use the timer to know when an hour had elapsed.